# PHP test for empty and/or null and/or unset array

Tags: php, codeigniter, logic

I want to keep this short. I don't know if I have the terminology correct, but I got this example from the *Codeigniter handbook Vol.1*.

```
if (count($args) > 1 || is_array($args[0]))
```

I've run into this problem numerous times. Depending on the datatype different tests are more appropriate. Some tests will just fail in unexpected ways.

How does one determine the most appropriate, and possibly, the most concise test?

Just to be clear I'm looking for the most effective way to test if an object/variable is ready to use, regardless of the datatype, if that's possible.

Also I don't want the solution to apply merely to lists like in the example. It should be widely applicable.

Answer (score 6):

Just use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(!empty($args)){
  echo 'Array is set, not empty and not null';
}
```

Comment: This _couldn't_ be used if the variable happened to be a string right?

Comment: @shakabra: Why not?, you could.

Comment: empty() will check for empty strings, too. @shakabra you should take a good look at the manual page that was linked. It spells out exactly what the function does.

Comment: Ok I don't know why I haven't used this more often. Thanks for the answer. But will empty() work with database resources if I'm using MySQL. That's been a real headache for me.

Answer (score 1):

use empty() `bool empty ( mixed $var )`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Comment: That's not PHP and it doesn't get anywhere close to covering all the use cases in my example.

Comment: @shakabra yes it is php, i should've included the link to manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @shakabra your example is also a bit different, it not only checks if $args has more than one element but also checks if $args[0] (the first element of $args) is an array as well

Comment: Sorry it was just a line of code that got me thinking about previous problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following function for a while.

You can add your own test for all possible variable types.

```
function is_valid_var($var)
{
  if ( isset( $var ) ) {

    // string
    if ( is_string( $var ) && strlen( $var ) == 0 ) return false;

    // array
    elseif ( is_array( $var ) && count( $var ) == 0 ) return false;

    // unknown
    else return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```